# Using group by to get distinct pairs from SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement which matches bids and offers and places them in another table for matching.
The select statement results in the following table below.

| bidder_user_id | dealer_user_id | bid_id | offer_id | bid_volume | bid_price | bid_market_time | row_offers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 13 | 8 | 11 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 1 |
| 13 | 13 | 8 | 12 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 2 |
| 13 | 13 | 9 | 11 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 1 |
| 13 | 13 | 9 | 12 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 2 |

The problem is when one or more bid/offer "matches" as seen with the above table. For `bid_id` 8 this matches both `offer_id` 11 and 12. Similarly for `bid_id` 9 this matches both `offer_id` 11 and 12.

The desired would be that the `bid_id` and the `offer_id` would be unique for each row. So for the first row above `bid_id=8` and `offer_id=11` these are unique so keep. For the second row `bid_id=8`, this is not unique as it occurred in the row previus so remove even though `offer_id=12` is unique. For the third row `bid_id=9` is unique but `offer_id=11` has already been matched in first row so remove this. For the fourth row `bid_id=9` and `offer_id=12` is unique so we can keep this. The desired result is shown below.

| bidder_user_id | dealer_user_id | bid_id | offer_id | bid_volume | bid_price | bid_market_time | row_offers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 13 | 8 | 11 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 1 |
| 13 | 13 | 9 | 12 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 2 |

Ignore that the same `bidder_user_id` and `dealer_user_id` are the same for now.

I have tried to group by the `bid_id` which results in the following.

| bidder_user_id | dealer_user_id | bid_id | offer_id | bid_volume | bid_price | bid_market_time | row_offers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 13 | 8 | 11 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 1 |
| 13 | 13 | 9 | 11 | 10.0000 | 0.1500 | 2021-03-04 10:45:00 | 1 |

The problem here is the `offer_id` 11 is being matched twice.

Grouping by both `bid_id` and `offer_id` will give just the original result so that is no use either.

The entire select statement is shown below I just wanted to explain the problem first, it is sorting the result of this select statement that is the problem.

```
/* Insert statement to insert matched bids/offers */ 
    INSERT INTO Marketplace_Matched(
        consumer_id,        /* Bidder */
        producer_id,        /* Offer */
        bid_id,             /* bid id */
        offer_id,           /* offer id */ 
        agreed_ta_tokens,   /* Volume */
        agreed_tb_tokens,   /* Price */
        market_time)        /* Market Time */
    SELECT  
        bids.user_id AS bidder_user_id,                 /* Bidder */
        offers.user_id AS dealer_user_id,               /* Offer */
        bids.bid_id AS bid_id,                          /* Bid ID */
        offers.offer_id AS offer_id,                    /* Offer ID */
        bids.bid_ta_tokens AS bid_volume,               /* Volume */
        bids.bid_tb_tokens AS bid_price,                /* Price */
        bids._bid_market_time AS bid_market_time        /* Market Time */
        offers.rn AS row_offers
    FROM  
        Marketplace_Bids bids
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (
                PARTITION BY /* Partition by the volume in the offer, could be multiple offers for same volume */
                    offer_ta_tokens 
                ORDER BY /* Order each partiton by the price low to high, this makes row 1 in each partition the lowest price offer for that volume*/ 
                    offer_tb_tokens 
            )rn /* Get the row number also back */ 
        FROM Marketplace_Offers
    ) offers
    ON
        /* Volume must be equal */ 
        bids.bid_ta_tokens = offers.offer_ta_tokens AND
        /*Price must be at least asking price */ 
        bids.bid_tb_tokens >= offers.offer_tb_tokens AND
        /* Market time must be same */ 
        bids.bid_market_time = offers.offer_market_time;
        
    *****POSSIBILY SOME GROUP BY?********
```

Comment: *Really the result should look like the following.* Why rows 1 and 4 are taken? Why not rows 2 and 3? What criteria?

Comment: @Akina I have updated to explain this a bit more, if it is still not clear let me know. For know I am trying to just go off the order in which they appear.

Answer (score 0):

Unique combinations without replacement. I don't know that there is a way to do that in a single query. This really needs a loop to remove "selected" bids from the pool; a stored procedure that loops though the records, assigns a winner and moves on to the next. Then you could query the results.

The answer to the question linked below describes this as more of an algorithm question instead of a query problem, and I tend to agree.

[How to create Combination of records (...no repetition allowed) ...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48013/how-to-create-combination-of-records-order-does-not-matter-no-repetition-allow)

Comment: Hi Geoff, thanks for the comment I'll give it a look. Maybe it is a case of rethinking this one, this is part of a bigger stored procedure run on a timer which removes offers and bids after they are matched, a loop may be the answer to this possibly